# Proof that function is real part of $\sec(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, harmonic-functions, hyperbolic-functions

I'm working on the following problem:

[image]

I've deduced that the key is to show that $u$ is the real part of $\sec(z)$. But, I'm getting stuck in the algebra and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Here's my work so far:

\begin{align}
\cos(z)&=\cos(x)\cosh(y)-i \sin(x)\sinh(y)\\
\text{sec}(z)=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}
&=\frac{1}{\cos(x)\cosh(y)-i \sin(x)\sinh(y)}
\cdot \frac{\cos(x)\cosh(y)+i \sin(x)\sinh(y)}{\cos(x)\cosh(y)+i \sin(x)\sinh(y)}\\
&=\frac{\cos(x)\cosh(y)+i \sin(x)\sinh(y)}{\cos(x)^2\cosh^2(y)+\sin(x)^2\sinh^2(y)}\\
\end{align}

Thus, I need only show that $\cos(x)\cosh(y) - i\sin(x)\sinh(y) = -1+\sin^2(x)-\sinh^2(y)$. However, this is not true, per my previous post.

Comment: $$u(x,y) = - \frac{\cos x \cosh y}{\cos^2 x + \sinh^2 y}$$

Comment: As the answer there shows, you just have the sign wrong. If $y=0$, you get $-\sec x$, not $\sec x$ from your formula.